# How to run multi "when" condition under same satge

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins pipeline, the user is required to choose a lab to deploy and if the "Set is developed deployment" is checked the pipeline is required to perform additional action.  When trying to have to multi "when" condition under the same stage it failed to run

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        extendedChoice(name: 'Lab to update', description: 'Select the labs on which you wish to deploy', multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'lab1,Lab2', visibleItemCount: 5)
        extendedChoice(name: 'Set is develop deployment', description: '', multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'Develop deployment', visibleItemCount: 5)
    }
    agent { label 'ansible.cyber.local' }

    stages {
        stage ('Deploy pyspark_dependencies on Lab 1 ') {
            when  { environment name: 'Lab to update', value: 'Lab1' }
            steps {
                echo "Stage-1"              
            }
            when  { environment name: 'Set is develop deployment', value: 'Develop deployment' }
            steps {
                echo "Stage-2"              
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add when conditions at the step level. You will have to either move the additional steps to a new stage or use an if condition. Take a look at the following example.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        extendedChoice(name: 'LabToUpdate', description: 'Select the labs on which you wish to deploy', multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'Lab1,Lab2', visibleItemCount: 5)
        extendedChoice(name: 'IsDev', description: 'Set is develop deployment', multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'Develop deployment', visibleItemCount: 5)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            when  { expression { params.LabToUpdate == 'Lab1' } }
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Do something"
                    if(params.IsDev == 'Develop deployment') {
                        echo "Do something additinal if second param checked."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```